# Extract all roots from a numerical expression

Tags: maple

I need to extract all roots (including complex `I` if it's there) from a numerical expression.
I'm interested at least in the case when there are no nested roots.
For example, if

```
f:=(3^(2/3)*2^(3/5)+3*I)/(4*2^(2/5)-2*sqrt(5)/7);
```

then the answer should be this:

```
A:={I,2^(2/5),2^(3/5),3^(2/3),5^(1/2)};
```

Or better, just base roots (it's not hard to get B from A though):

```
B:={I,2^(1/5),3^(1/3),5^(1/2)};
```

I've had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672006/get-all-cubic-roots-from-an-expression), but I could use `indets` for that. But with numerical expressions `indets` doesn't help.

One way I could think of is to use [op](https://fr.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=op), but there can be quite sophisticated expressions (like many nested fractions, terms, multipliers, etc.). Maybe Maple already has some function that gives all the entries in one list or set?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here.  Are you looking for values of `I` that make `f` zero?  Because that's a lot simpler than what you have stated.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, f is just a number, not a function. ```I``` is imaginary unit: ```I^2=-1```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish that:

```
f := (3^(2/3)*2^(3/5)+3*I)
     /(4*2^(2/5)-2*sqrt(5)/7):

indets(f, radical)
  union {ifelse(has(f,I),I,NULL)};

          /    (2/5)   (3/5)   (2/3)   (1/2)\ 
         { I, 2     , 2     , 3     , 5      }
          \                                 /
```

[edit] By the way, you claimed that you could not utilize `indets` here, making this quite different from an earlier Question by you.

But, as shown above, you can utilize `indets` (except for the I part), as shown above. You could also utilize `indets` with a refinement/generalization of the `type` used in my answer to your earlier Question. That is, you can compare these two, for this particular followup example,

```
indets(f, `^`(anything,
              And(positive,rational)));

indets(f, radical);
```

Also, for your `B`,

```
f:=(3^(2/3)*2^(3/5)+3*I)/(4*2^(2/5)-2*sqrt(5)/7):
A := indets(f,`^`(anything,
                  And(positive,rational))):

subsindets(A,
           `^`(anything,And(positive,
                 rational)),
           u->op(1,u)^(1/denom(op(2,u))));

                / (1/5)   (1/3)   (1/2)\ 
               { 2     , 3     , 5      }
                \                      /
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot that ```indets``` sees more with additional options.